# std::string == operator not working in code

Tags: c++, string, loops

So I am making a simple calculator using c++ which inputs a string from the user and takes that input as the operation.

```
std::cout<<"Enter your operation: ";
std::string operation;
std::cin>>operation;
while(operation != string("+")|| operation != string("-") || operation != string("*"))
{
    std::cout<<"Invalid operation! Please enter a valid one: ";
    std::cin>>operation;
}
```

However no matter what I input, I get the error message "Invalid operation! Please enter a valid one: ".
Please help me out here, thanks!

Comment: `==` and `!=` are related but different operators

Comment: this question is asked on a regular basis. Try to check what happens for the conditions for some example input with pen and paper / your rubber duck

Comment: Thinks about what you are telling the code to do.  If `operation` is `+`, what is the result of your loop?  Does that change if t is something else?

Comment: `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: Why all the drive by down votes? First time contributor has made a reasonable attempt to ask a question and has provided some code. Sure it could be improved on, but is there really a need for the down votes?

Answer (score 3):

You almost had it. You simply need to use the boolean operator *and* `&&` instead of *or* `||` in your loop condition:

```
std::cout<<"Enter your operation: ";
std::string operation;
std::cin>>operation;
while(operation != string("+") && operation != string("-") && operation != string("*"))
{
    std::cout<<"Invalid operation! Please enter a valid one: ";
    std::cin>>operation;
}
```

You want to keep looping for as long as `operation` is not a `+` and is not a `-` and is not a `*`. So if it's either one of those, the condition will be `false` and your loop will end.

Comment: Oh my! That was a silly mistake on my part lol. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This should be in a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa :D excuse me?

Comment: I've already added this answer as a comment go check it.

Comment: ahahahaahah maybe. then excellent!

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa answers should go to answers. Comments are for clarifing the question not for giving answers

Answer (score 0):

You have a logical error. The error message must be reached if the while condition is true. So, this condition must have `&&` instead of `||` to guarantee the coverage of your condition.